# No exact matches in call to initializer in a count of an array

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I try to extract some words from a txt file but I can't manage it. This is my code :

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var allWords : [String] = []
    
    func startGame() {
        if let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start", withExtension: "txt") {
            if let startWords = try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL) {
                allWords = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                return
            }
        }
        
        if allWords.isEmpty {
            allWords = ["silkworm"]
        }
        
        fatalError("Could not load start.txt from bundle.")
    }
    
    var body: some View { 
        VStack{ 
            Text(allWords.count) 
                .onAppear(perform: startGame) 
                .font(.system(size: 30)) 
                .frame(width: 1000, height: 75) 
                .background(Rectangle() 
                .foregroundColor(.white)) 
                .border(Color.black, width: 1) 
        } 
    }
```

I have an error on the line `Text(allWords.count)` which tell me "No exact matches in call to initializer"
And If I replace the `allWords.count` by for example `allWords\[0\]` I have a fatal error which tell me "Index out of range"

I don't really understand what happen

I have already tried other functions but I always have similar errors

I just want to have for example the second element

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Try allWords.count.description, just one option. You need a String not a number

Comment: Or `Text("\(allWords.count)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of Swift/SwiftUI's many super-vague error messages, *No exact matches in call to initializer* almost *always* means that the error is due to the types mismatching / the wrong type being used as input for a given function. In your case, you are trying using an `Int` (returned by the `.count` method) with a `Text()` view, which takes a `String` as a parameter.

Some possible solutions:

- `Text(String(allWords.count))`
- `Text("\(allWords.count)")` (credit to @Paulw11's comment)
- `Text(allWords.count.description)` (credit to @lorem ipsum's comment)